# How to use `dataTaskDidReceiveResponse` callback?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use `dataTaskDidReceiveResponse` of the `SessionDelegate`of the manager but can't find how to use it. I'm new to swift (but experienced with objective-c) and can't found the correct syntax.

I have tried something like

```
manager.delegate.dataTaskDidReceiveResponse =  {
    return NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow
  }((session:NSURLSession, task:NSURLSessionDataTask, response:NSURLResponse)-> NSURLSessionResponseDisposition)
```

and some other variants. I don't know if it's just a syntax issue or my comprehension of swift/Alamofire that is lacking.

Can anyone help me found the right path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

`manager.delegate.dataTaskDidReceiveResponse = 
      {(session:NSURLSession, dataTask:NSURLSessionDataTask, response:NSURLResponse) -> NSURLSessionResponseDisposition in
            return NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow
      }`